# Echo token in CMD

Tags: cmd

What I am trying to do is add quotation marks around the tenth token of a text files so a number would read "55555" instead of 55555. While leaving the other tokens untouched.

What I have as of now which doesn't work is:

```
FOR /F "skip=1 delims=, tokens=*" %i in (file.txt) do 
IF tokens EQU 10
    echo "%i" >> data.txt
ELSE
    echo %i >> data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F "skip=1tokens=1-9,10*delims=," %i in (file.txt) do (
 >>data.txt echo(%%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m,%%n,%%o,%%p,%%q,"%%r",%%s
)
```

should work for you.

Comment: Did this help you, Bob?